# Unir a href a um button

Tags: php, mysql

Em um fomulário eu tenho esse link:

```
 <a href="chk-gerente.php?nro_pergunta=<?php  echo $nro_pergunta; ?>">Próximo</a>
```

E esse botão:

```
 <button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" >REPONDER</button>
```

Duvida:
 Esse é um sistema de perguntas,que lista pergunta a pergunta.
 O link próximo trás a nova pergunta e o responder faz o método GET fazendo o insert no banco.
 É possivel passar o link do próximo dentro do botão fazendo uma coisa só? tipo,quando eu clicar em responder ele faria o insert e logo após traria a próxima pergunta ?
 Algo tipo isso:

```
 <button a href="chk-gerente.php?nro_pergunta=<?php  echo $nro_pergunta; ?>" 

type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" >REPONDER</button>
```

Já tentei dessa forma ai e não deu certo.

Comment: when you have a button, embed it in a form: <form action=YOUR_URL method=get>
<input type=hidden name=nro_pergunta value=<?php echo $nro_pergunta; ?>
<button...> </form> see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461658/are-button-html-tags-outside-of-a-form-valid

Comment: Perfect, all right , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um JQuery (ou Javascript) para tornar padrão a abertura de link com o `href` em `button`

```js
    $("button").click(function() {

      if ($(this).attr("href")) {
        alert('Irá redirecionar para ' + $(this).attr("href"));
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
      }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button href="chk-gerente.php?nro_pergunta=1" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">REPONDER</button>
```

Entretanto para seu caso em especifico pode criar um `input hidden` e então redirecionar a pessoa.

Por exemplo:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="proxima" value="<?= $nro_pergunta ?>" />
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" >REPONDER</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['proxima'])){

//...

$pergunta = (int)$_GET['proxima'];
// Número da pergunta (se não for número remove o (int)!)

header('location: chk-gerente.php?nro_pergunta='.$pergunta);
// Redireciona    
}

?>
```

Dessa forma, irá obter `nro_pergunta` do `hidden` e irá redirecionar para o URL escolhido.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pessoal pelas dicas,testei e deram certas,mais a que ficou como eu exatamente tava precisando foi a do: @hgfdgd :

```
when you have a button, embed it in a form: <form action=YOUR_URL method=get> <input type=hidden name=nro_pergunta value=<?php echo $nro_pergunta; ?> <button...> </form> see also:
```

Mais obrigado mesmo todos.
 Forte abraço.

Answer (score -2):

Coloca a função `<a>` entre ele. Resolveu meu problema

```
<a><button></button></a>
```